# Import created framework to xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I am building a new project in Swift 2, i found this really nice library https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka . but I am having a really hard time importing it to my project. Can someone help me with some steps on how to import this kind of libraries ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: That framework can be installed via cocoa pods, check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEAjvNRdZa0

Comment: @thefredelement thanks veeeeery much !!!!